# Adding two relations via ParseRelation always sets the first class as target class

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am having a weird issue here.

The class `Points` I want to save data into, has two columns `race` and `challenge` which are relations to other classes with the same name.

I have asked this question on [Parse.com forums](https://parse.com/questions/android-adding-two-relations-via-parserelation-always-sets-the-first-class-as-target-class) as well

On the client side on Android, if I add the relation via `pointsObject.put("race", raceObject)`, it throws an error saying that the type of **`"race" is Relation and I am providing a *Pointer`**

The iOS Counterpart of the app I am working on is completely able to save relations nicely - Happily Coded about 2 hours ago

When I use `ParseRelation` to add a one-to-many relationship, it takes only the first class as target class.

This code should explain:

```
ParseRelation<ParseObject> initiatorChallengeRelation = initiatorPoints.getRelation("Points");
        initiatorChallengeRelation.add(challenge);
        initiatorPoints.put("challenge", initiatorChallengeRelation);


ParseRelation<ParseObject> initiatorRaceRelation = initiatorPoints.getRelation("Points");
        initiatorRaceRelation.add(race);
        initiatorPoints.put("race", initiatorRaceRelation);
```

The first block of code sets the target class for the relation as "Challenge".
The second block tries to set the target class of the new ParseRelation object to "Race", but `initiatorRaceRelation.add(race)` is where it fails and throws an error : "IllegalArgumentException: Related object object must be of class Challenge, but Race was passed in."

I used Eclipse Debugger to check the data in the both Relation objects and found the thing about target classes being the same

Any help on where I might be going wrong?
I have been dealing with this issue since more than 12 hours and its really become a roadblock for me.

Any help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `Points` a relation? From what you have mentioned, it seems so.

Assuming that initiatorPoints is a Points Object, you should get the `challenge` relation using

```
ParseRelation<ParseObject> initiatorChallengeRelation = initiatorPoints.getRelation("challenge"); //for challenge
```

then

```
initiatorChallengeRelation.add(challenge);
```

Similarly, for race

```
ParseRelation<ParseObject> initiatorRaceRelation = initiatorPoints.getRelation("race"); //for race

initiatorRaceRelation.add(race);
```

I think you need not even use `initiatorPoints.put("challenge", initiatorChallengeRelation);`
Once, you say

`initiatorPoints.saveInBackground(callback)`, Parse updates the changes in the object by itself.

But do not forget to save the object once you have added the relation data. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have submitted the same answer on the question that you put up on Parse.com forum so that if someone stumbles across the question gets the answer right away! I hope this is fine :)